# Default toolbar and status bar not showing into xml preview in android studio 3.3

Tags: android-studio

The base theme of android studio did not showing the default Actionbar and Status Bar in the XML preview option in android studio 3.3 version.

It looks like this:

[image: image1]

But it used to/should look like this:

[image: image2]

How do i get it to show the navigation bar and action bar again?

Answer (score 19):

Solution is very simple... step by step:

You should do > Design in Design/Text, there is a eye icon above (top left corner) (click) and click ***Show Layout Decorations*** Taa taaaa :)

Answer (score 15):

I also updated Andriod Studio to 3.3 and faced this problem also. At first I thought I should downgrade the Studio Version then I saw I EYE icon and marked **Show Layout Decorations** option. See below

[image]

Answer (score 5):

And now (nov 2020, Android Studio 4.0.1) it's **Show System UI**

[image]

Comment: This works only if you select an element on the XML.