# How to enable layout decorations (e.g. Actionbar) in AndroidStudio xml-preview?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I'm working on a small android-project, and I want to show the `action bar` in the `XML-preview`. Like this:

[image: actionbar visible]

I've already done some research and found this question: [Default toolbar and status bar not showing into xml preview in android studio 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54219396/default-toolbar-and-status-bar-not-showing-into-xml-preview-in-android-studio-3). This question provides that you have to use the eye-icon and mark "Show Layout Decorations".

[image: eye icon]

The problem is that I don't have any eye-icon.

[image: actionbar not visible]

I'm using AndroidStudio 3.1.2.

Comment: Fixed it! Updating android studio was the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your Android Studio and If still you face the error then try re-installing hope it will solve your error.