# How do I tell Android Studio to display the name of the app?

Tags: android-studio

In [Udacity](https://classroom.udacity.com) the 'Adding the Button' lesson uses Android Studio Version 3.3. It shows that the name of the app is displayed "Dice Roller' in the Preview with Design layer.

[image]

Using Android Studio Version 3.5.2 I did:

```
File>New>New Project>Choose your project>Empty Activity>Next>Configure your project>Finish
```

When I select:

```
app/res/layout/activity_main.xml
```

The Preview with Design layer does not show the name of the app.

[image]

How do I tell Android Studio I want the name of the app displayed?

Comment: [eye icon above (top left corner) (click) and click Show Layout Decorations ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54278851/101954)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the theme for the preview, to any theme which shows the `Toolbar` might work. If you'd get a bigger LCD display, you might also see the drop-down to switch the theme (or even define it in `AndroidManifest.xml`). It might not be directly supported, because it's rather useless information (which the least applications display). That's because it's the default `Toolbar` from the theme... if you'd inflate a custom `Toolbar`, this would be visible in the preview without messing around.

Comment: 'If you'd get a bigger LCD display' sounds like a rather expensive way to display the drop-down. The '>>' provides access to the hidden items, or adjusting the size of the panes or using full screen.