# Android studio does not show status bar, navigation bar & default toolbar in layout preview

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using the updated version of Android Studio.
In the previous version, the design view was just like the image(left side). But now I am missing all of these top and bottom view (right side of the image). Do I need to install plugins or what should I do to get a proper view of the left side image?

The left image shows the correct view, the Right side is the preview from the updated Android Studio.
[image]

Comment: Are you using Android Studio 4.1?

Comment: why do you need to see something that is not part of your app?

Comment: Check my answer. Hope that is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you are using Android Studio 4.1 as you had mentioned you are using the latest version.

Selecting the below-shown option in the preview pane should make the status bar, default toolbar, and navigation bar visible.

[image]

For anyone using AS 3.3 this answer would help:
[Default toolbar and status bar not showing into xml preview in android studio 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54219396/9636037)